# Creating schema with mongoose and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Trying to create new mongoose schema but the issue is I am always getting new collection with only two columns: _id and __v. That's it, no my columns from schema.
Here is the schema code:

```
import DataAccess from '../DataAccess';
import IUserModel from '../../model/interfaces/UserModel';

var mongoose = DataAccess.mongooseInstance;
var mongooseConnection = DataAccess.mongooseConnection;
class UserSchema {
  static get schema() {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      },
      firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
      }
    });

    return schema;
  }
}

var schema = mongooseConnection.model<IUserModel>('Users', UserSchema.schema);

export default schema;
```

User model is pretty simple:

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');

interface UserModel extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

export default UserModel;
```

Data access layer:

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');

class DataAccess {
  static mongooseInstance: any;
  static mongooseConnection: mongoose.Connection;

  static connect(): mongoose.Connection {
    const MONGODB_CONNECTION: string = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname';

    if (this.mongooseInstance) return this.mongooseInstance;

    this.mongooseConnection = mongoose.connection;
    this.mongooseConnection.once('open', () => {
      console.log('Connected to mongodb');
    })
    this.mongooseInstance = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_CONNECTION);
    return this.mongooseInstance;
  }
}

DataAccess.connect();
export default DataAccess;
```

Once I am trying to create new user it creates new document in database but with only two default columns ...

Comment: Well, I think it is ok because I am importing it accordingly. Anyway, I tried to change the names but still with no success, only two fields in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault, the code is ok, but the issue was in posting values to the server via postman extension in google chrome. Just had to add Content-Type = application/json. That's it.
Guess I can close this question now.